# How do I copy the formatting of a number to another number?

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
strA = '0.8243'
strB = '12.3'
strC = float(strA) + float(strB)

print strC # 13.1243...I want it formatted like that of strB...13.1
```

strA and strB will change and will have unknown amount of decimal places. However, I always want the decimal places to retain that of strB. Is that possible?

Note: if strB = '12', then float(strB) = 12.0...I want no decimals in this case (e.g. match the original string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strA = '0.8243'
strB = '12.3'
C = float(strA) + float(strB)
print '{:.{}f}'.format(C, len(strB.partition('.')[2]))
```

**Output**

```
13.1
```

Comment: I will accept when it allows me to..thx for the very quick response!

Comment: You are mixing new-style `str.format()` and old-style string interpolation with `%`. You can do everything with the new format like this: `'{:.{}f}'.format(C, places)`

Comment: @BasSwinckels Great. This is what I was trying to do and I didn't know how to do. Where can I read about it?

Comment: I was reading through [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) that introduced this format while you beat me for the answer. The manual has a [section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) about it as well.

Comment: Instead of the additional `if '.' in...` change to use `places = len(strB.partition('.')[2])`

Comment: @JonClements Updated my answer with that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `decimal.Decimal` class here, and amend to how you want rounding to occur:

```
strA = '0.8243'
strB = '12.3'

from decimal import Decimal as D
a, b = map(D, [strA, strB])
print (a + b).quantize(b)
# 13.1
```

And `strB = '12'` gives you `13` as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Can't do any simpler:

```
strA = '0.8243'
strB = '12.3'
strC = float(strA) + float(strB)
c=len(strB.split('.')[1])
d=round(strC, c)
print(d)
```

Ans: 13.1